# How to prevent Data loss in Pandas.to_excel when handling very long string of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my input file (csv)

| id1,id2 |
| --- |
| 233924749247492472,9284372492472497294749 |
| 298347230474308444,9472943274947429427477 |

I want to read this file in a dataframe, remove the delimiter and then write it back in .xlsx file

Few code combinations that I have already tried

Attempt 1:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path,  sep=Delimiter, float_precision=None )
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
df2.to_excel(filepath, index=False)
```

Attempt 2:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path, sep=delimiter)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine=None)
df3.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Attempt 3:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path, sep=delimiter)
df3.to_excel(path, index=False)
```

Everytime I am getting the same output in excel file

I am seeing a data loss in the first column. The output looks like this:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 233924749247493000 | 9284372492472497294749 |
| 298347230474309000 | 9472943274947429427477 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, pandas will cast integer as `int64`. This is enough for integer between `-2⁶³` and `2⁶³-1 = 9223372036854775807`. So if any element in a column exceeds this value, pandas will set the column type to object.

Apparently, Excel truncates big int (smaller than `2⁶³-1`) but not objects. So a solution would be to set the dtypes of all your columns to objects:

```
pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype=object).to_excel('output.xlsx')
```